# Suppose $A$ and $B$ are positive definite matrices. Will $ABA$ , $ABA^*$ and $AB$ be positive definite matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Suppose $A$  and $B$ are positive definite matrices (not necessarily symmetric).

Will $ABA$ , $ABA^*$ and $AB$ be positive definite matrices? $A^*$ is $A$ transpose.

I have no idea. Because I dealt with only symmetric matrices in this context. But $A$ , $B$ are not necessarily symmetric matrices here.
Can somebody help me out?

Comment: how?@SahibaArora

Comment: By saying that you "deal with only symmetric matrices in this context" I take it that your definition is a matrix $A$ is positive definite iff it is symmetric and $\langle x, Ax \rangle \gt 0$ whenever $x$ is nonzero.

Comment: please read the question once again..@hardmath

Comment: As far as I know ''positive definite'' is a property defined only for symmetric matrices:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Further_properties

Comment: The typical definition of positive definite requires the matrix be self-adjoint.  It seems like this is not the case in your question, so I editted to make this assumption explicit.  If I am wrong, rollback my edit.

Comment: I also knew it.. But https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66520/if-a-and-b-are-positive-definite-matrices-is-ab-positive-definite confused me..@hardmath Emilio Novati

Comment: Thanks for clarification!

Comment: "But $A,B$ are normal matrices here." [Normal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix) is a technical term denoting a matrix satisfying $A^*A=AA^*$. Is that what you mean, or do just mean $A,B$ may not be symmetric?

Comment: U can answer supposing that $A$ and $B$ are symmetric. If they are not P.D then we will be done...

Comment: U can answer supposing that $A$ and $B$ are symmetric. If they are not P.D then we will be done...@hardmath

Comment: Note that $A^*$ is ordinarily the *conjugate transpose*.  For  a real matrix this amounts to the same thing as transpose, but for complex matrices it is not generally the same.  In the case of complex vector operations, *positive definite* (defined as $\langle x,Ax \rangle \gt 0 $ for any nonzero $x$) implies self-adjoint (i.e. implies Hermitian).