# Construct example - $A$ and $B$ have strictly positive eigenvalues, but $A+B$ and $AB$ have strictly negative eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

As a follow-up to [this question I asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2689391/how-to-construct-negative-definite-ab-if-a-and-b-are-positive-definite/2689427#2689427), I wondered what would happen if I imposed the weaker condition of having positive eigenvalues, rather than being positive definite.

How do I construct an example of two matrices $A$ and $B$ such that:

1) $A$ and $B$ have strictly positive eigenvalues.
2) $A + B$ has strictly negative eigenvalues (is this even possible?).
3) $AB$ has strictly negative eigenvalues.

Generally, I'm unsure how to begin going about constructing an example of a matrix that satisfies these properties.

Comment: What do you know about the trace of a matrix?

Comment: Sum of elements on the main diagonal?

Comment: Yes, but it's also the sum of the eigenvalues.

Comment: Okay, I see that, but I'm not sure how to use it for this purpose.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with using that trace($AB$)  = trace($BA$)?

Comment: $tr(A+B)=tr(A)+tr(B),$ so 1) and 2) can't both hold.

Comment: Similarly, using $\det(AB) = \det(A) \det(B)$, you could conclude 1 and 3 are incompatible in the case of odd dimension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trace of a matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues.  Also, $$\mathrm{tr}(A+B) = \mathrm{tr}(A)+\mathrm{tr}(B).$$  If $A$ and $B$ have strictly positive eigenvalues, then 
$$\mathrm{tr}(A),\mathrm{tr}(B)>0\implies \mathrm{tr}(A+B)>0,$$ 
so it is not the case that $A+B$ has negative eigenvalues.

For a case where $A,B$ have only positive eigenvalues and $AB$ has only negative eigenvalues, take $$A=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&4}, B=\pmatrix{4&-3\\3&-2}$$
The eigenvalues of $A$ are obviously $1$ and $4$, both eigenvalues of $B$ are $1$, and both eigenvalues of $AB$ are $-2.$  I constructed this just by messing around with the characteristic polynomials.  I don't have any insight into the problem at all.

Comment: Sum, not product.

Comment: *sum of eigenvalues, and in your first line of working, I think you meant tr(A+B).

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes, that's what I meant.  Thanks.

Comment: @TheveshTheva Thanks.  I'm not sure if I'm worse at typing, or at proofreading.

Comment: Well, it's no issue, since you pointed me in the right direction to begin with! Do you have any pointers on case (3), comparing A and B to AB?

Comment: As Daniel Schelper pointed out in his comment, since the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues, you can rule out odd dimension.  I've been thinking about even dimension, but I don't have any insight yet.

Answer (score 1):

if $A$ and $B$  are symmetric and  strictly positive definit, you can not have neither $A+B$ nor $AB$ to be negative definite

Comment: Yep, I agree with that. Does that still hold true if $A$ and $B$ have positive eigenvalues, but are not necessarily symmetric or positive definite?

Answer (score 1):

For an example where $A$ and $B$ have all positive eigenvalues while $AB$ has all negative eigenvalues, consider 
$$ A = \pmatrix{10 & 8\cr -9 & -7\cr},\ B = \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & 2\cr} $$
$A$ and $B$ both have eigenvalues $1$ and $2$, while $AB$ has a double eigenvalue $-2$.

Comment: Brilliant - could I ask how you constructed this example?

Comment: A little optimization and experimentation.